# Термин для названия функции и типов её аргументов

Tags: терминология

Есть прототипы функций:

```
1.int funct(float,float);
2.int funct(float,float,int);
3.void funct(float,float).
```

Функции 1,2 могут мирно сосуществовать, поскольку происходит перегрузка. Функции 1,3 или 2,3 не могут мирно сосуществовать в одном пространстве имен или классе, поскольку их имена и типы,кол. аргументов совпадают.

Так вот сам вопрос: что не должно совпадать в перегруженных функциях, назовите одним словом. То есть, как назвать "имя функции"+"тип и количество аргументов", используя одно слово? Слово это я забыл, где ни искал - не нашел.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сигнатура?
Интерфейс?
По-моему сигнатура.

Comment: Это [сигнатура функции](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#.D0.A1.D0.B8.D0.B3.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.82.D1.83.D1.80.D0.B0_.D1.84.D1.83.D0.BD.D0.BA.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B8). Согласно википедии: "часть общего объявления функции, позволяющая средствам трансляции идентифицировать функцию среди других".

Comment: Поддерживаю - слово "сигнатура" первое, что приходит в голову.

Answer (score 0):

1. Прототипы одноимённых функций должны различаться чем-то помимо возвращаемого значения и дефаултных значений.
   Похоже, это называется сигнатурой.
   Хотя, всегда считал, что сигнатура - это то же самое, что прототип...
2. Функции 2 и 3 могут сосуществовать, поскольку имеют разное количество параметров.